# How to fix 'ORA-06550' on executing PL/SQL in Oracle Apex using Web Source

Tags: oracle-apex

[image]Showing error ORA-06550 when i execute PL/SQL code in a dynamic action on oracle apex.

I have created a web source with parameter referring mentioned below link:-
https://www.lrayner.com/blog/query-an-address-from-a-web-source-module-apex-18-1-1

```
                declare  
              l_context apex_exec.t_context;
              l_parameters  apex_exec.t_parameters;
              l_baridx pls_integer;
              l_logidx      pls_integer;
              l_baridx      pls_integer;
              l_locidx      pls_integer;
              l_ufidx       pls_integer;
               
            begin 
               apex_exec.add_parameter (
                  p_parameters => l_parameters,
                  p_name       => 'zipcode',
                  p_value      => :P3_ZIP_CODE);
               
               -- Open Web Source
               l_context: = apex_exec.open_web_source_query (
                  p_module_static_id => 'tst',
                  p_parameters       => l_parameters);
                  
               
               l_logidx:= apex_exec.get_column_position (l_context, 'LOGRADOURO'); 
               l_baridx:= apex_exec.get_column_position (l_context, 'BAIRRO');
               l_locidx:= apex_exec.get_column_position (l_context, 'LOCALITY');
               l_ufidx:= apex_exec.get_column_position (l_context, 'UF');
               
               while apex_exec.next_row (l_context) loop
                  
                  if apex_exec.get_varchar2 (l_context, l_logidx) is null or 
                     apex_exec.get_varchar2 (l_context, l_locidx) is null then
                     :P3_ADDRESS := null;
                     :P3_CITY := null;
                  else
                     :P3_ADDRESS:= apex_exec.get_varchar2 (l_context, l_logidx) || 
                                     ',' || apex_exec.get_varchar2 (l_context, 
                                     l_baridx);
                     :P3_CITY:= apex_exec.get_varchar2 (l_context, l_locidx) || 
                                  '('|| apex_exec.get_varchar2 (l_context, l_ufidx) 
                                  ||') ';
                  end if;
                  
               end loop;
               
               -- Close Web Source
               apex_exec.close (l_context); 
            exception
               when others then
                  -- Close Web Source 
                  apex_exec.close (l_context);
            end;
```

i expect to compile it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error when you are trying to compile a code and the error says exactly what you are doing wrong, you should try starting from there...

That message is usually related to syntax error and what happens is that there's a space between the assignment operator for the **l_context** variable, just remove it to fix:

```
       -- Open Web Source
       l_context := apex_exec.open_web_source_query (
          p_module_static_id => 'tst',
          p_parameters       => l_parameters);
```